# How to change Selenoid GRID chome's langage?

Tags: docker, robotframework, selenoid

How can I change chrome langage in Selenoid GRID. In local, my test pass with french langage but when I run them on the GRID, Chrome is in english, which creates some issues with my date component (dd/mm/yyyy in fr and yyyy-mm-dd in en)

I run my test with this command :

./Helpers/run-test.py -i LANCEMENT:daily1  --launchvariables Debug_local -E DEVD  --keepbrowseropened --seleniumspeed 0.4

And I am looking for something like --language fr or something

[error due to date component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVmmd.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set browser locale in environment variables.

```
{
"chrome": {
    "default": "64.0",
    "versions": {
        "64.0": {
            "image": "selenoid/chrome:90.0",
            //...
            "env" : ["LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8", "LANGUAGE=ru:en", "LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8"]
        }
    }
}
```

}